How can I access the ManagerInsights API from within a Homey app
Is it possible to access the ManagerInsights API from within a Homey App?
The Permission documentation shows only a few of the available "Manager..." API's.
I added "homey:manager:insights" to the app permissions, but then I get an compilation error (Error: Invalid permission: homey:manager:insights).

Not sure why you think you need special permissions, the documentation states that "You can access this manager through the Homey instance as this.homey.insights".
For instance in your app:
class MyApp extends Homey.App {
  async onInit() {
    this.log = await this.homey.insights.createLog(...);
  }
}



well, because some of the API's where specified in the documentation and when I call this.homey.insights.getLogs() I get an empty array.

Did you create any logs beforehand? Otherwise there's nothing to return. Also, if an API requires specific permissions, you'll get an error when you call it, not just an empty result.

Can I only retrieve the logs I created with the current app?

Ah, yes there is a difference between the ManagerInsights from the SDK and the ManagerInsights from the Web API. I had read the  documentation of the Web API first to find a solution for what I want. Can I use the Web API from an app?

Yes, you can use the Web API from apps, although you do need permissions for that (and not all API endpoints are accessible; however, it's not really properly documented which ones are and aren't available). An example app that uses the Web API for Insights is Insights Graphs.
